# Correct mathematical expression

Tags: notation

I am a biologist. My apologies if I my question is too basic.

I am writing a scientific manuscript and I would like to express the following with a correct mathematical expression: for a list of numbers (from $x_1$ to $x_n$) calculate the product of $x_1$ to $x_n$ every time $x$ is above $0$.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Is what you want the product of all the positive numbers in the list?

Comment: yes, something like this [for (i in 1:length(vector)){while (vector[i]>0){x=vector[i]*x}}] but expressed with correct words or a correct mathematical expression for a scientific manuscript.

Comment: I think then there is an answer below that does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You probably look for
$$
\prod_{\substack{1\leq j\leq n \\x_j>0}} x_j,
$$
where I assume that $x$ above $0$ means $x_j>0$ (you did not define $x$).